# Why does the Add (used button to add a preferred job location) remain disabled?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I did the following:

1. I typed *Berlin* into the input field
2. In the drop-down box, I selected *Berlin, Germany*

but the 'Add' button remained disabled.

[image: Screenshot of the GUI showing the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, build is heading out to production now.

We're trying to reduce the amount of API calls to Google's Places API for place details and this usage was inadvertently changed to be ID only when it actually relies upon more than just the ID.

Comment: Indeed, it works now